# Copying folder contents preserving the folder structure using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have the source folder structure as shown below

```
c:\TestResults
|-- Log
|   |-- xyz.pdf
|   `-- Reports
|       `-- rp.pdf
|-- Keywords
|   |-- key.txt
|   |   `-- pb.ea
|   `-- reports
|-- Test
|   |-- 11.pdf
|   |-- 12
|   `-- Log
|       |-- h1.pdf
|       `-- Reports
|           `-- h2.pdf
`-- Dev
    |-- st
    |-- ea
    `-- Log
        `-- Reports
            `-- h4.pdf
```

I need to copy all the "Log" folders while maintaining the folder structure. The destination path is "c:\Work\Logs\TestResults". The resultant structure should be as shown below.

```
c:\Work\Logs\TestResults
|-- Log
|   |-- xyz.pdf
|   `-- Reports
|       `-- rp.pdf
|-- Test
|   `-- Log
|       |-- h1.pdf
|       `-- Reports
|           `-- h2.pdf
`-- Dev
    `-- Log
        `-- Reports
            `-- h4.pdf
```

Is there an easy way of achieving this using a powershell script? Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's the code that I have written so far. It flattens the folder structure but doesn't maintain the hierarchy. I am new to powershell scripting. Please help.

```
$baseDir = "c:\TestResults"
$outputDir = "c:\Work\Logs"
$outputLogsDir = $outputDir + "\TestResults"
$nameToFind = "Log"

$paths = Get-ChildItem $baseDir -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name.EndsWith($nameToFind)}

if(!(test-path $outputLogsDir))
{
   New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $outputLogsDir
}


foreach($path in $paths)
{
   $sourcePath = $path.FullName + "\*"   
   Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath | Copy-Item -Destination $outputLogsDir -Recurse -Container
}
```

Comment: As is this is a "give me teh codez" question. I suggest you take a look here and try some code first https://www.adamtheautomator.com/copy-item-copying-files-powershell/

Comment: I will edit the question to include the code that I have written. The problem that I am having is that the folder structure is getting flattened out and doesn't maintain the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is as below. it will copy the item and dir if any part of it has "\log" in it.

```
$gci = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\TestResults" -Recurse

Foreach($item in $gci){
    If($item.FullName -like "*\log*"){
        Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $($item.FullName.Replace("C:\TestResults","C:\Work\Logs\TestResults")) -Force
    }
}
```